# jQuery each blocking code when listening to a wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, addeventlistener

I suppose to add a `click` event to all `selected` element, the question is:

1. why I cannot use `el` to add the event and become the listener.
2. If I use `el` the whole block of code stopped running and seems stuck in each loop.

This is the code that runs correctly

```
$( ".selected" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){

    });
});

console.log("at reach")
```

This is the code that wrong:

```
$( ".selected" ).each(function(index, el) {
    el.on("click", function(){

    });
});

console.log("out of reach")
```

Comment: You want `$(".selected").on("click", function() { ... });` - please note that you are trying to use [selector.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) as [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: `el` is the dom node, not a jQuery object. Don't need `each` as noted but would work doing `$(el).on('click',...`

Comment: You don't need to iterate through all selected elements to attach the click handler: that is implicitly done when you do `$('.selected').on('click', ...)`.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I know that but the question is after running the wrong code, why the code is blocked and not running continually, like a console.log after this function not running. That confuses me.

Comment: because you have an error, there is no on() method in DOM.

Comment: because `el.on()` isn't a function and throws error...look in your browser console

Comment: a simple way to check this would have been to do `console.log(el)`

Answer (score 1):

> 1. why I cannot use `el` to add the event and become the listener.

You can't attach click event to DOM element `el` using the jQuery `on()` method, you could instead cast the element using `$()` :

```
$(el).on("click", function(){
    //Your logic
});
```

> 2. If I use el the whole block of code stopped running and seems stuck in each loop.

That because you're trying to call a jQuery method on DOM element, so normally you'll get :

> Uncaught TypeError: el.on is not a function

**Suggested solution :**

But you don't need no loop here you could attach the click event to all the elements with the given selector using :

```
$( ".selected" ).on("click", function(){
      //Your logic here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `That because you're trying to class a jQuery method on DOM element.`

so if the it cause an error, why the console not display any error?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in jQuery it shows

> function
>
> Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
>
> A function to execute for each matched element.

And if you look up [Element in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element)

> An element in the Document Object Model (DOM)

So you are treating a DOM element as if it were a jQuery object. You would need to wrap it in jQuery to turn it onto a jQuery object just like you do with `this`

```
$( ".selected" ).each(function(index, el) {
  $(el).on("click", function(){

  });
});
```

So why does the console log line show up? Because the browser encounters and error when you try to call on() method on an element that does not have an on method. Your developer console should have the error `VM279:2 Uncaught TypeError: el.on is not a function`